# Fullscreen Artifacts Using Canvas

Tags: java, rendering, fullscreen, java-canvas

I am working on my new game "[Wave 2](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4AZGzr3HML0VkxyR0hacDAtcTQ)". When the application is not in full-screen, it renders using Canvas and Graphics to directly draw on the canvas. No artifacts are formed when out of full-screen.

However when going into full-screen, when rendering, it forms artifacts on the display, which is most noticeable in the rectangles in the center. As can be seen in this [image of artifacts on the display](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4AZGzr3HML0YzJlUmxEZWV2Y28).

When in full-screen, the game must render onto an image so that it can be stretched to fit the display. But I don't think you can stretch in such a way to cause this.

I've tried to set the Graphics rendering hints. Which had no effect on the artifacts.

Comment: can you show us how you do all this?

Comment: The code that is most likely causing the problem can be found here

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4AZGzr3HML0REhrNUVUOHAtWW8 
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4AZGzr3HML0a1JTTmg0QnFCSk0

Comment: Here's the main class https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4AZGzr3HML0eVNuRElNa2VqMGM

Comment: thats  alot of code; my general suggestion is to keep the aspect ratio of the image - it s also unclear that artifacts you mean: the rectangle boundaries? if you dont specify it down to some concrete code I cannot answer - some one will do it